# Monitoring all running and spawning JVMs

Tags: java, memory, jvm, jenkins, out-of-memory

I have a 8Go compilation server, running a Jenkins instance, a Jenkins slave agent. All jobs run the same script sh. This script launches others scripts and a big ant build. In this build, several JVM can be launched (javac with fork, junitreports, etc etc ...).

I need to track a OutOfMemoryError. But I can't monitor the spawned Java processes with a tool because they are temporary.

I'm searching for a tool tracking all current and future JVM running on the server, and displaying memory graphs. Does it exist ?

Comment: I don't understand why it has been closed. Whatever, JVisualVM is exactly what I was searching for. I didn't know it was shipped with the JDK by default.

Comment: I don't see either how this is 'not constructive'. One might argue that this is a superuser question, but then again its about JVM processes. I vote for reopening.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop/ might also be an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. I know of several tools to monitor/inspect JVM instances, but as far as I remember most of them rely on the JVM already being up and running.

- [JVM Monitor](http://www.jvmmonitor.org/)
- [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html)

I guess a solution would be to have a periodically running script what checks for JVM instances (use the command `jps`) and then starts other monitoring tools...

Comment: JVisualVM did the trick, even remotly.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of such a tool.

But you can do something similar with a shell script running periodically

```
jps | grep -v -i 'jps'  | cut -d' ' -f 1 | xargs -n1 jmap -heap
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running JConsole. It's free and a really easy tool to profile. You can track objects life, quality of the application  (By examining the Eden Space area and other areas). You can get a complete memory usage analysis of your JVM.

By default, you get JConsole when you download JDK.